# Difference between boost::fiber::yield and boost::fiber:sleep_for when using fibers with boost asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast, boost-fiber

I was experimenting with boost asio with fibers and found that `boost::this_fiber::yield()` and `boost::this_fiber::sleep_for(x)` seem to behave differently when using the round robin asio scheduler provided in fibers [examples](https://github.com/boostorg/fiber/blob/develop/examples/asio/round_robin.hpp).

The setup is that we have one thread create two fibers which loop indefinitely:

1. Fiber 1 uses async read with a beast websocket.

   ```
    while (true) {
      beast::flat_buffer buffer;
      boost::system::error_code ec;
      ws.async_read(buffer, boost::fibers::asio::yield[ec]);
      LOG(INFO) << beast::make_printable(buffer.data());
      boost::this_fiber::yield();
    }
   ```

2. Fiber 2 just loops and yields.

   ```
    while (true) {
      boost::this_fiber::yield();
    }
   ```

With this setup, no websocket reads actually happen as we never reach the logging statement right after the `async_read`. However if we switch Fiber 2 to be

```
    while (true) {
      boost::this_fiber::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
```

We now are able to print out the websocket reads. Curiously, if we reduce the sleep_for time to a low number like `std::chrono::nanoseconds(1)`, the reads no longer happen.

Why does this behavior occur? Is this a subtlety of the round robin asio scheduler? My hypothesis is that somehow Fiber 2 with `boost::this_fiber::yield()` will prevent io_context from running any completion handlers, but I'm pretty unsure.

Thanks!

EDIT:

A self contained example with asio async timers can be found [here](http://gist.github.com/alz2/4448455caee4ffa89260e171466fac06) which exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: This seems like an unfortunate form of deterministic starvation ("scheduler resonance" if you will). Can you make the sample self-contained? If you suspect "[...] prevent io_context from running any completion handlers" then you can do it with something trivial like a timer instead of a websocket.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I've made a self contained example with async timers which shows the same behavior: https://gist.github.com/alz2/4448455caee4ffa89260e171466fac06

Comment: I would add that to the question itself. I had to do multiple fixes to the round_robin.hpp to make it compile. Maybe it's worth asking at the boost dev mailing list, because it's experimental